# Getting NullPointerException when calling getwritableDatabase()

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I am trying to retrieve all data in my database, but getting null pointer exception while getting instance of db it is returning null,  i dont know why it is occurring. I have posted my logcat too please check it and help me to solve this...

DataBaseView.java

```
package com.vibrator;

import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class DataBaseView extends Activity{
    DataBaseAdapter DataBaseAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> al;
    Cursor cursor;
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.database_view);
        System.out.println("entered in database");

        ListView list1 =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        al = new ArrayList<String>();
        DataBaseAdapter=new DataBaseAdapter(this);  



            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();




         //DataBaseAdapter.open();
        System.out.println("entered try");

        cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from DETAILS", null);
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {
                         System.out.println("entered if loop");
                         String id =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                         String name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                         //String pattern =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PATTERN"));
                         //store the values in arraylist
                         al.add(id+". "+name);                      
                    } 
                     while (cursor.moveToNext());                                   
             }

                 else{
                     System.out.println("cursor is null");           
                 }
                 cursor.close(); 
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, al);

            list1.setAdapter(adapter);


            DataBaseAdapter.close();    

    }


    }
```

logcat:

```
08-06 12:41:14.124: I/System.out(10311): entered in database
08-06 12:41:14.184: D/AndroidRuntime(10311): Shutting down VM
08-06 12:41:14.184: W/dalvikvm(10311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vibrator/com.vibrator.DataBaseView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at com.vibrator.DataBaseView.onCreate(DataBaseView.java:35)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-06 12:41:14.294: E/AndroidRuntime(10311):    ... 11 more
```

DataBaseAdapter.java

```
package com.vibrator;

//import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
//import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class DataBaseAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Vibrator.raj.db";

    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"DETAILS"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ ""
                                        + "NAME  text,"
                                        + "PATTERN text); ";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public  DataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Method to openthe Database  
    public  DataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
    }
    public  DataBaseAdapter openr() throws SQLException 
    {
            db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            return this;
    }
 // Method to close the Database  
    public void close() 
    {
            db.close();
    }
    // method returns an Instance of the Database 
    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
            return db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dbHelper is never initialized in DataBaseView and is therefore null.

Comment: No it is initialized i have passed context to DataBaseAdapter.. `public  DataBaseAdapter(Context _context) {context = _context;dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }`

Comment: Yes, you have initialized it in DataBaseAdapter (as you should), but it does not reflect back to DataBaseView. You should use your DataBaseAdapter instead of using the helper in DataBaseView. For some reason you have commented out DataBaseAdapter.open() and are trying to use an uninitialized helper instead.

Comment: The same error is occurred even though i use DataBaseAdapter.open()